# Is it ok to separate data to train on different time instead of putting all in one go?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network, training

So let say i have 10,000 images ready to be trained on. But my GPU cannot handle all of that.

So the questions is:

- Can i train the model 10 times with 1000 images each time, with same epochs and batch for each time ? (Save the checkpoint after each time)
- Will that affect the result ?
- If this works, will this even affected by the type of model (Regressor, Classifier, ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you start training with 10000 images, your model can generalize data better. Of course you can get good accuracy by your method, but it is not expected to be as good as using all of the images. Being a classification or regression problem does not matter in this aspect.